# What is the 'npm' command and how can I use it?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

**What is npm?**

Whenever I browse through some project they ask me to run npm command, something like this

```
npm install -g node-windows
```

I went through some blog posts to learn about npm and I installed Node.js. However, when I run the above code in Node.js, I get the following errors:

[image]

When I browsed further, I came to know that the windows user can run the command from the cmd prompt window, but when I do that I get some output like this:

[image]

Which just generate a text file nothing else.

My questions:

1. How can I get started with the `AngularJS2`?
2. How can I run an npm command?
3. Do I require a command prompt to run the npm command (in Windows), or I can just use Node.js?

When I use the command npm install in my command prompt, I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Check this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html . It will help you out .

Comment: this is the site which i checked and got confused, the thing is i am not able to download the files using npm command, is there anything i should know about the node.js settings

Comment: i dont know whats wrong with this people who mark me down, for GODssake, this is a forum which helps people to get the solution for the problem, dont get so nerd and haste to mark down on some very helpful questions

Comment: You are right @Lijin I am having the same issue  get many -ve mark I hope someone notice this .

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41693932/edit) (it covers command line input and output as well).

Answer (score 1):

1. How to get started with the angularJS2

   Follow [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) link and set up the project by following instructions
2. How to run a npm command

   npm stands for Node Package Manager, and therefore you need Node.js installed before you can run npm commands.

   Follow [this](https://nodejs.org/en/) and install the latest version. And restart the command prompt.
3. Do I require a command prompt to run npm commands (in Windows), or can I just use Node.js?

   Yes, you need to run npm commands from the command line (in Windows).

   E.g., npm install

   You get the warning because there is no *package.json* file present where you are running the command.
   **ENOENT** stands for Error NO ENTrey

Navigate to the project folder using the following command and then run npm install

`cd <projectpath>`

Comment: well, i will go through the link which you have provided but, as i have said in my question, i am getting error when i run the command in both nodejs and command prompt, you can see the screen shot for the same

Comment: I presume you don't need to install node-windows. Navigate to your project directory and run 'npm install'.

Comment: using command prompt. Note: you have to be inside the project folder where the package.json file is present

Comment: when i use command prompt,i get an warning message, let me update you the warning message in my quuestion section

Comment: i get some error, when i added the json file and ran the command npm install

Comment: do you want me to update the error, i appreciate your answer but i am not able to vote you cause some ass has marked my question down and i dont have enough score to vote people

Comment: If you downloaded the project from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html#!#download package.json will already exist

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS 2 website has everything you need to be covered. Their *quickstart* guide alongside with the *quickseed* zip file helps a lot.

But, in case you missed some points:

- yes, you will need **npm/NodeJS.** So, download the latest distribution and have a clean installation of it.
- you can execute the ***npm*** command with its parameters from within the Windows *cmd*.
- the [quickseed](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip) ZIP file contains all the files you need to see a live and quick example running locally. **Unzip** it on your workplace and **navigate to it using the windows cmd.** When inside the **root** folder of the unzipped package, execute ***npm install*** and right after it ***npm start***.

Take the [learning path](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/learning-angular.html). Step by step, all your questions will be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an admin prompt for global installation (`-g`).

Comment: They aren't quite asking how to install an npm package globally, that command was an example.